# Don't understand how Math.random() works in java

Tags: java, random

Why does the following code prints just 25?

```
while(true) {
    int pos = (int) (Math.random() * (26 ));
    if (pos > 24)
        System.out.println(pos);
}
```

If `Math.random()` returns a number from `0` to `1` then shouldn't the code above print also `26 (1*26 = 26)`?

Comment: It returns a number from `0` to *almost* `1` (but not `1`).

Comment: Your codes prints 26 for me (sample output - `25
25
25
26
26
26
26
25
25
25
26
25
25
26
25
26
25
25
26
26
26...`) thanks to your call to `Math.ceil`.

Comment: Sorry . I tested it with math.ceil to see something and i forgot to remove .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a positive double greater than or equal to 0.0 and **less than** 1.0.

`(int)` will truncate doubles, that is - it will remove all the numbers after the decimal point leaving only the integer part - **it will not round the number!**

Because `Math.random()` will never be 1, the random number multiplied be 26 will always be lass then 26. So `(int)` will truncate the 25.xyz , it will remove all the numbers after the decimal point leaving only 25.

That is way you will never get 26.